# Force a delete cascade with no constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, cascade

I'd like to know if it's possible to force a cascade when deleting in MySQL?

I know that a in order to be able to delete all the childs of a parent this has to exists:

```
REFERENCES table (fk) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

But my tables doesn't have it, so, back to my question, is there a way to force it?

Comment: Can you add the constraint? It makes life a lot easier when deleting 'top level' primary keys., as the the database does all the work. Otherwise you have to have a script, procedure etc. that deletes all the children first then works back up the tree. Maybe not difficult but can be tedious.

Comment: Yes, there is: add the constraint :)

Answer (score 4):

One either puts it in the original table creation, or *attempts* to establish it after the fact with `ALTER TABLE`

mysql Manual Page on [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

If one chooses to establish after the fact, the same rules apply as seen in the above link. Failing those or data pre-existing such that the enforcement will fail with the ALTER TABLE call, then the attempt will fail to establish the fk with a cascading delete.

See that manual page, and look into `ADD CONSTRAINT` and `DROP CONSTRAINT`. There is no altering of an existing constraint. Rather one must drop it then re-add it.

An alter add example"

```
ALTER TABLE lunches
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_lunches_users`
FOREIGN KEY (`studentId` )
REFERENCES `students` (`studentId` )
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Also of interest is `foreign_key_checks` that should be investigated. That is, is one willing to temporarily disable them.